# Why does my image float even after using clear:both?

Tags: html, css, css-float

The image with the class `call-img` is supposed to not float since I used `clear:both` for it. But it still does.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img class="logo-img" src="images/logo.png">
    <div class="topnav-link">
        <span>Menu&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/menu.png">
    </div>
    <img class="call-img" src="images/call.png">
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    padding-top: 2.5em;
}
.logo-img {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
}
.menu-img {
    width: 20px;
}
.topnav-link {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: .8em;
}
.menu-img,
.topnav-link span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.call-img {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
    align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the `call-img` is on the next line not the same line?

Comment: Please respond to comment and tell us you want image in next line or what?

Answer (score 0):

change css to

```
.call-img {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "clear" has to come *after* whatever element you want "unfloated" (return to the default flow of the DOM). In this case, I would give the `<header>` element a css property of clear:both.

Another option is to clear exactly after your  element.

```
.call-img::after{
content: "";
clear: both;
}
```